# Font installation issue with chessfs

Tags: fonts, chess

Ah, fonts again! I need to use a chessboard in one of my articles, probably using skak or chessboard, but I'm not even there yet. Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chessfss}
\begin{document}
 A simple \sympawn to get me started.
\end{document}
```

Resulting in

> Font SkakNew-Figurine at 600 not found

So, clearly it's a font issue. I am using TeXLive on a Win7 machine, by the way. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you run `pdflatex`? And do you have a font in `...\texlive\2013\texmf-dist\fonts\type1\public\skaknew\SkakNew-Figurine.pfb`??

Comment: I figured it out, file path was misspelled, go figure ... Thanks!

Comment: How can a wrong path mess up the fonts in this way? The fonts should work out of the box in texlive unless there is a problem with the map files.

Comment: Exactly. The map file was not found due to a faulty path.